# How to make a function return after 5 seconds passed in Python?

Tags: python, function, time

I want to write a function which will return after 5 seconds no matter what:

```
def myfunction():
    while passed_time < 5_seconds:
        do1()
        do2()
        do3()
        .
        .
    return
```

I mean, this function run for 5 seconds only, after 5 seconds, it should end, and continue with other function:

```
myfunction()
otherfunction()   ----> This should start 5 seconds after myfunction() is executed.
```

Best Regards

Comment: Is there any chance that the execution of any of your functions lasts longer than 5 seconds?

Comment: What if half way through function `do2`, 5 seconds has past?

Comment: Yes, if I leave it on its own, myfunction() may last for hours. But, I want it to end after 5 seconds, and the code should continue with the next function.

Comment: In that case you need to run the two functions on different `threads` and start the second one 5 seconds after the first one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeout on a Python function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call)

Comment: If 5 seconds passes, myfunction() should return after the last statement is executed in myfunction().

Comment: @alwbtc: That's fairly doable. See my answer

Comment: @alwbtc I think we are still unsure of what exactly that you want. Are you saying you want to do as much as possible of `myfunction` in 5 seconds and then kill it? Do you want it to keep running in the background? It seems like you are using a round-about way to solve another problem. Could give more context to your code?

Comment: No I dont want it to run in background. `myfunction()` may last for 20 hours. But, for example, 3 hours of it is sufficient for me. When 3 hours passes since `myfunction()` starts, it should end, and the program should continue with the next function: `otherfunction()`

Comment: Do you actually want to loop the contents of `myfunction`? (Assuming the calls ran in negligable time)

Comment: No, there are no loops in myfunction(). But it lasts too long. To be more specific, myfunction() is an optimizer, and optimization lasts too long. 3 hours of optimization is sufficient for me, because it will not yield a siginificantly better result after 3 hours. Therefore I want to cutoff after 3 hours. So that the next optimizer otherfunction() will begin. This way the whole optimization process will be completed in shorter time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
def myfunction():
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() < start + 5:
        do1()
        do2()
        do3()
```

Note that this will stop after *at least* 5 seconds - if `do1`, `do2`, and `do3` each take 3 seconds, then this function will take 9 seconds.

---

If you want to cut off `myFunction` between these calls, you can do:

```
def myfunction():
    todo = itertools.cycle([do1, do2, do3])
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() < start + 5:
        todo.next()()
```

This case would take 6s

Comment: What if there are no do1, do2, do3 in myfunction(), but plain statements?

Comment: @alwbtc: You can interweave `if time.time() < start + 5: return` statements between every other statement instead of using the while loop

Comment: Nice. I'm going to try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a chance that the execution time of your functions is longer than the interval between firing these functions, you'd have to start these functions in another thread or process.

Example with `threading`:

```
import time
import sys
from threading import Thread


def f1():
    print "yo!!"
    time.sleep(6)


def f2():
    print "boring."
    time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    try:
        for f in [f1, f2]:
            t = Thread(target=f)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
    finally:
        [t.join() for t in threads]
```

I understood the question in the way that you do not necessarily need to kill/end one function after exactly 5 seconds. Your main goal is to fire up the functions with a 5 second interval. If you need to 'kill' the functions after a certain time, this won't be trivial using threads: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. How do you know all these things? I don't even know a module named threading exists. Do you study all modules?

Comment: Yes, we study all the modules that we need. These things take time and the experience grows over the months/years. Ontopic: I now realize that you start talking about hours instead of seconds and that being able to 'kill' a 'function' is now a requirement. If it is about hours and heavy tasks, you should consider spawning subprocesses using the multiprocessing module. They have a `terminate` method sending a signal to the subprocess. You can handle this singal in the subprocess and act correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
import time 
start=time.time()   

stuff={1:do1,2:do2,3:do3,...}
i=1

while time.time() <= start+5:
    stuff[i]()
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the way you've defined your problem, I think this is a good situation for using a generator based co-routine. That is, change `myFunction` to a generator that `yield`s every time it has finished with a step of its processing (e.g. `do1` or `do2`) and run it from a loop that checks the time.

Here's a simple implementation that repeatedly runs a single `somework` function, but you could easily call different functions, or even do work directly in the `myFunction` generator:

```
import time

def somework():
    print "Doing some work!"
    time.sleep(2)

def myFunction():
    try:
        print "Started myFunction()"
        yield somework()
        yield somework()
        yield somework()
        yield somework()
        yield somework()
        print "Done with myFunction()"
    except GeneratorExit:
        print "Exiting myFunction() early!"

def main():
    start = time.time()
    gen = myFunction()
    for _ in gen:
        if time.time() > start+5:
            gen.close();
```

There are some benefits to using this structure:

1. First off, `myFunction` gets to choose where it `yield`s to the outer loop, so it won't get killed at an unexpected time. If it's manipulating some external data structure, you can ensure it always yields with everything in a consistent state.
2. Second, `myFunction` can yield intermediate values, if that is useful. The example code above yields `None` (since that's the return value from `somework` but you can change that easily. The main loop puts the latest yielded value in the `_` variable (which is not used), but you can rename that variable and use its value in the timeout block if you want.
3. Finally, by catching the `GeneratorExit` exception, `myFunction` can run any cleanup code that it needs before it shuts down.